# Django AbstractUser Inheritence Error

Tags: python, django, abstract-class

I'm still pretty new to Django, and have been having a problem defining my own user model that inherits from the Abstract User in Django. However, I have users already in the databse (with only usernames and passwords) and when I try to migrate the changes, I get the error that the email field is required and doesn't have a default value.

What confuses me is that I looked it up in the docs, and at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/ the email field is clearly listed as optional. Furthermore, when I try to override the email field I get an error that my field clashes with the existing one.

Why is it giving me this error, and how do I fix it?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    additionalFields = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EmailField` is a text field in the database, and 'empty' text fields are saved as an empty string (`''`). They are not empty (`NULL`)  on a database level, and the column is defined as `NOT NULL`. What you need to do is set a default of `''`, then the migration will work.

Comment: Thanks, so the problem was that NULL is different from an empty field